# Managing WiFi on IOS 8

Tags: ios, wifi

As for testing purposes I'd like to get into WiFi settings much more deeper and want to use some WiFi managing app like Airport on OSX which I recently did use on OS X and wonder what's the counter part on iOS, if there's any.

Get an idea here:
https://superuser.com/questions/286457/connect-to-wifi-network-using-mac-terminal

Am keen on any feedback, as you can imagine.

Comment: You want to know how to connect to WiFi via command line on an iOS device? Presumably your device is jailbroken then?

Answer (score 1):

There is [Airport Utility](https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/airport-dienstprogramm/id427276530?mt=8) by Apple which allows you to review and change the configuration of any Apple WiFi device in the current network.